# Does Chef powershell_script have limited privileges?

Tags: powershell, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am encountering several situations where, in a Chef recipe with powershell_scipt, a command appears to fail, whereas if I run the same command in powershell outside of Chef, the same command works.

The two in particular are "regedit", which I am trying to use to set a key for app compatibility and the other is "net use z:...." to created a mapped drive.  Both of these seem to work fine if I run them in powershell, but if I use them inside a recipe inside powershell_script, they don't appear to do anything.

So I'm wondering is this because Chef runs commands that are inside powershell_script at some lower privilege level?

Also if so, how do I change it so that the regedit and net use would work?

Thanks,
Jim

EDIT 1:  This seems to work for adding the registry entry I needed:

```
registry_key "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\AppCompatFlags" do
  values [{
    :name => "{2b9034f3-b661-4d36-a5ef-60ab5a711ace}",
    :type => :dword,
    :data => 00000004
  }]
  action :create
end
```

That prevents the compatability popup that I am getting when we run the Sharepoint installer.

EDIT 2:  I hope that this is ok, but for the record and more visibility and hope that I remember this, I found this re. mapping drives in Windows and Chef:

[Mount windows shares on a windows node with Chef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040512/mount-windows-shares-on-a-windows-node-with-chef)

and:

https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-1267

I haven't tried that yet, but that seems like the answer to my drive mapping need.... hopefully..

Answer (score 2):

The chef client service runs as Local System (`SYSTEM`) by default.

In Windows, that user has full privileges on the local system, like `root` basically, but on the network it authenticates as the computer object.

So it you are trying to use `regedit` to change something in for example `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` then you need to remember that the code will not see the same "current user" as you will when you run it in interactively. Also, regedit is an .exe; you should really do what you need through the PowerShell providers or .Net objects.

For `net use` you are trying to map a drive. It's likely that the computer account doesn't have the rights to the share that your user has. Again, `net.exe` is a separate executable. `net use` maps a drive to a drive letter (usually) and you shouldn't be doing that in a configuration script, in my opinion. You should access the UNC path directly, but either way I still think that you're probably running into a permissions issue here.

You could change the credentials of the service to use a user account that has all the rights you want, but before doing something like that you should consider changing your workflow to not need that.

Comment: I understand what you said, about we should be doing the net use (to map a network drive) and the regedit outside of the Chef flow, but in our scenario, they want to have kind of bare Windows images to start with and then to do the installations remotely.  They do not want to prep the machines for specific uses, e.g., they don't want to have one Windows image for a Sharepoint machine and another Windows image for an Exchange machine.

Comment: Sorry I hit the Enter key :).   Anyway, you mentioned UNC directly.  How do I do that?  I mean I can use say \\192.168.0.236\foo in the install path, rather than map the drive, but using UNC can I authenticate also?

Comment: Also, for the regedit, what alternate would you suggest?  What I am trying (and failing) is regedit inside powershell_script.  It doesn't give me any error... it just does nothing (doesn't change registry).

Comment: This seems to have worked for the registry change I needed - oops I'll add it above in the OP I think.

Comment: The way to map a drive within powershell is with `New-PSDrive`. You should be able to supply a `-Credential` parameter to that, but again I think trying to look at the issue different might help. For example, why do you need a network drive? Perhaps it would be better to host an archive on an HTTP server, then during config, download it, extract it, and work with the files locally.

Comment: Side note on SYSTEM account, it has no right to do network calls, if a service need to do network calls it has to be run as the NETWORKSERVICE user. [More details on service accounts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686005(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @Tensibai `SYSTEM` can make network calls just fine. If you mean authenticated network access like accessing a share or querying AD, it can do those too. The key is that it will be authenticating as the machine account, not a user called `SYSTEM`.

Comment: @briantist right, it's the LocalService account which has not this rights. (The link is still good for the reference anyway :p)

Comment: So I'm all good now - for the registry edit, I used the "registry_key" and for the drive mapping, I used the "mount", both are inbuilt in Chef now.  Thanks!