# Chef - Installing a Windows Package from a Mapped Drive

Tags: windows, powershell, chef-infra

I am trying to install a package from a mapped drive.  However, chef says my source path is an invalid location even though I know it is the correct location.  Do I need to map the drive first, before Chef recognizes the source path?  I looked online in a couple places and could not find an answer.

```
case node['platform']
when 'windows'
  windows_package 'QualysCloudAgent' do
    source '\\Server#\Location1\Qualys_agent\QualysCloudAgent.exe'
    options '-argumentlist "CustomerId={etc...etc...etc..} ActivationId={etc...etc..etc...}"'
    installer_type :custom
    action :install
  end
end
```

The error that I get when the chef client runs is that the source location is in invalid source, even though I can get to the source location by typing it in on the server itself.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.  Error That I receive is below.

```
   * Source for package QualysCloudAgent does not exist
   ================================================================================
   Error executing action `install` on resource 'windows_package[QualysCloudAgent]'
   ================================================================================

   Chef::Exceptions::Package
   -------------------------
   Source for package QualysCloudAgent does not exist

   Resource Declaration:
   ---------------------
   # In c:/chef/cache/cookbooks/qualys/recipes/qualys_configure.rb

    18:   windows_package 'QualysCloudAgent' do
    19:     source '\\Server#\Location1\Qualys_agent\QualysCloudAgent.exe'
    20:     options '-argumentlist "CustomerId={etc...etc...etc...} ActivationId={etc...etc...etc...}"'
    21:     installer_type :custom
    22:     action :install
    23:   end
    24: end

   Compiled Resource:
   ------------------
   # Declared in c:/chef/cache/cookbooks/qualys/recipes/qualys_configure.rb:18:in `from_file'

   windows_package("QualysCloudAgent") do
     package_name "QualysCloudAgent"
     action [:install]
     default_guard_interpreter :default
     declared_type :windows_package
     cookbook_name "qualys"
     recipe_name "qualys_configure"
     source "p:\\Server#\\Location1\\qualys_agent\\qualyscloudagent.exe"
     options "-argumentlist \"CustomerId={etc...etc...etc...} ActivationId={etc...etc...etc...}\""
     installer_type :custom
   end

   System Info:
   ------------
   chef_version=14.14.25
   platform=windows
   platform_version=6.3.9600
   ruby=ruby 2.5.7p206 (2019-10-01 revision 67816) [x64-mingw32]
   program_name=C:/opscode/chef/bin/chef-client
   executable=C:/opscode/chef/bin/chef-client

2020-01-12T22:21:50-08:00] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications before re-raising exception

unning handlers:
2020-01-12T22:21:50-08:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
unning handlers complete
2020-01-12T22:21:50-08:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
hef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 14 seconds
2020-01-12T22:21:51-08:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to c:/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
2020-01-12T22:21:51-08:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
2020-01-12T22:21:51-08:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::Package: windows_package[QualysCloudAgent] (qualys::qualys_configur
 line 18) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::Package: Source for package QualysCloudAgent does not exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're installing a package, it's safe to assume you are running `chef-client` with elevated permissions. Any network drives you map that are visible in Explorer, will not be usable in an elevated process. You will either need to:

- Use the UNC path in place of a letter drive
- Map the drive during the Chef run (required if the full UNC path would exceed 255 characters)

If you opt for the latter approach, you can use the [`mount` resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_mount.html) to [map a network drive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24040512/584676).